# Pydub export error - Choose encoder manually

Tags: python, audio, mp3, encoder, pydub

I'm trying to export a file as mp3 in pydub, but I get this error:

> Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format mp3 is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually

How do I select an encoder manually, what is the default encoder, and how could I enable it?

PS: My Pydub opens mp3 files without any problem. I'm using Windows and Libav.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443850/error-when-exporting-with-pydub-how-to-install-mp3-codecs-for-pydub#20445742. Have you tried encoding as a `wav` file to ensure that your file is encodable? Check to see that your mp3 codec is installed.

Comment: Yes, it exports as wav. And it loads mp3.

Comment: Playing mp3s requires a decoder, whereas writing mp3s requires an encoder. What OS are you using and what is your mp3 encoder? Are you using `ffmpeg`, `gstreamer`, `ubuntu-restricted-codecs`,
 etc. You can download and compile the source for Lame (mp3 encoder) on  Mac/Linux/Windows here: http://lame.sourceforge.net/download.php .

Comment: I don't think I have an encoder....

Comment: Here's a useful link. Audacity is an audio editor and if you try to export mp3s without the encoder it brings you to this page. I post this because it has useful links about the nature of encoders and links to liblame that does not require compiling from source.  http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/faq_installation_and_plug_ins.html#lame

If you're on Linux, installing the codec is easy. Otherwise, check out the files here: http://lame.buanzo.org/#lamewindl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find which codecs are available with `ffmpeg -codecs` or `avconv -codecs` and on the line with `mp3` you'll see something like:

```
DEA.L. mp3                  MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (decoders: mp3 mp3float mp3_at ) (encoders: libmp3lame )
```

`D` means ffmpeg can decode
`E` means it can encode
`A` means it's an audio codec
`L` means it's a lossy encoding

but the most important part is the `encoders: …` portion

I *think* you'll need to pick one of the encoders listed and tell pydub to use it (I'm not sure why, this isn't required on my machine - but it probably depends on your ffmpeg installation)

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file(…)
sound.export("/path/to/output.mp3", codec="libmp3lame")
```

Comment: I don't think I have ffmpeg....I followed an alternative installation mentioned in pydub documentaion using libav....

Comment: @Daniel Updated my answer to include the libav command as well

Comment: if you do not have an mp3 encoder installed with libav maybe try installing ffmpeg instead in hopes that it bundles an mp3 encoder? I do not use windows so I, unfortunately, don't know much about your options wrt getting support for specific formats

Answer (score 7):

The other solution did not work for me. The problem for me was that the `ffmpeg` version that came installed with Anaconda did not seem to be compiled with an encoder. So instead of:

`DEA.L. mp3                  MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (decoders: mp3 mp3float mp3_at ) (encoders: libmp3lame )`

I saw:

`DEA.L. mp3                  MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (decoders: mp3 mp3float mp3_at )`

Without the `(encoders: ...)` part.

My solution was to do this:

- `ffmpeg -codecs | grep mp3`, to check if there is any encoder (there isn't!).
- `conda uninstall ffmpeg`
- Open new terminal window.
- `brew install ffmpeg --with-libmp3lame`
- `ffmpeg -codecs | grep mp3`, to check if there is any encoder (now there is!).

Comment: for some reason, just conda uninstall FFmpeg on my Mac 10.14.5 (Mojave) worked without having to install FFmpeg through brew.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as [Emiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2899924/emiel), where the `ffmpeg` version available in Anaconda did have an mp3 encoder. I solved the problem another way, by installing [this version](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ffmpeg) of `ffmpeg` from the `conda-forge` channel. I used:

```
conda install -n <anaconda-env> -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

Now using `ffmpeg -codecs | grep mp3` the mp3 encoders show up:

```
 DEA.L. mp3      MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (decoders: mp3float mp3 ) (encoders: libmp3lame libshine )
```